# Can I access the request URL in a AGS Server Object Extension (SOE)?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-server, server-object-extension

I would like to obtain the full URL of a REST request inside of an ArcGIS Server SOE.

I would like to return the full URL to an output file.  But, the service may be exposed on different servers or through different urls on the same server via a proxy.

I'm working with ArcGIS Server 10.1 on Windows with IIS.

Comment: I couldn't understand second question correctly. Could you explain more infomation?

Comment: I was just trying to explain why I can't hard code the host portion of the URL.  The service will be deployed to different servers with different URLs.  Some of the servers have a different URL when accessed externally.  In that case the request goes through a proxy server, so the server has no knowledge of its own URL, which rules out getting the host portion of the URL from a server property.  So getting it from the request seems like the best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did find a solution for this.  A property set of server environment information can be retrieved with the following code:

```
        EnvironmentManager envMgr = new EnvironmentManager();
        UID envUID = new UID();
        envUID.Value = "{32d4c328-e473-4615-922c-63c108f55e60}";
        object envObj = envMgr.GetEnvironment(envUID);
        IServerEnvironment3 serverEnvironment = (IServerEnvironment3)envObj;
        IPropertySet serverPropsTemp = serverEnvironment.Properties;
```

There are a number of useful reference paths in the property set that provide the information needed to return absolute URLs instead of relative paths for generated files and other resources.

```
"AdminTokenURL": "http://REDACTED/arcgis/admin/generateToken",  
"RestURL": "http://REDACTED/arcgis/rest",  
"AdminUser": "REDACTED",  
"SoapURL": "http://REDACTED/arcgis/services",  
"AdminURL": "http://REDACTED/arcgis/admin",  
"AdminUserPassword": "REDACTED",  
"RequestContextURL": "http://REDACTED/arcgis"
```

Thanks to Ajit for the lead in this ESRI forum thread: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-enterprise-questions/is-it-possible-to-access-httpcontext-inside-soe/m-p/520020